# Loading multiple external SWFs within a main swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I’m building a website that loads multiple swfs within one main swf. I would also like some swfs to unload when i click on the button situated on it.

could someone please help me on this.

Currently I’m only able to load one swf with this code, can I somehow load more that just one swf by default? you can see the code below:

```
var swf:MovieClip;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

var defaultSWF:URLRequest = new URLRequest("swf/gallery.swf");
loader.load(defaultSWF);
addChild(loader);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load more than one SWF at a time you just need to create multiple Loader objects and then load into them.

For example:

```
var gallery:Loader = new Loader();
gallery.load(new URLRequest("swf/gallery.swf"));
addChild(gallery);

var other:Loader = new Loader();
other.load(new URLRequest("swf/other.swf"));
addChild(other);
```

As for unloading the SWFs - you just need to reference the Loader object and call it's unloadAndStop method.

Answer (score 0):

As an additions to Branden's answer, if you want to load the items in sequence you could reuse the same Loader instance, and have something like:

```
var gallery:MovieClip;
var other:MovieClip;
var swfClips:Array = [gallery,other];
var swfUrls:Array = ['swf/gallery.swf','swf/other.swf'];

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loaderReady);
loader.load(new URLRequest(swfUrls[0]));

function loaderReady(event:Event):void{
    swfClips[0] = MovieClip(event.target.content);
    if(swfUrls.length){
        swfClips.shift();
        swfUrls.shift();
        loader.load(new URLRequest(swfUrls[0]));
    }else{  trace('all swfs are loaded');   }
}
```